# Updating Label from another class C# Not working

Tags: c#, wpf

So I am working on a piece of software that will let me to connect to some Arduino and control it. Now, I have a method used to handle all the code for Arduino (serial port, baud rate, port name, etc) and everything works just fine.

Now, my challenge is here: I have a label in my window and I want to change the content of that label to show me when it the software is connected to my Arduino and when is disconnected. I have the code, it seems to be correct, it runs and all but it does not update my label. I tried in different ways and it still didn't work so I made a MessageBox in one of the methods that should update my label and that message box is showing when the button (connect button) is pressed, so that method works, but not the line that should update my label. Any ideas why and how can I fix that?

ArduinoControl code:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace MyApp
{
    static class ArduinoControl
    {

        static SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();

        //Pentru conectarea la MainWindow;
        static Arduino ard = new Arduino();

        public static bool isConnected = false;    


        public static void ConnectToArduino()
        {
            try
            {

                string portName = ard.tboxPortName.Text;
                sp.PortName = portName;
                sp.BaudRate = 9600;
                sp.Open();
                ard.DisplayConnected();
                isConnected = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Please give a valid port number or check your connection. " +
                    "If the port number is correct but the error persist, please check if your Arduino device is correctly connected.");
            }
        }


        public static void DisconnectFromArduino()
        {
            try
            {
                sp.Close();
                isConnected = false;
                ard.DisplayDisconnected();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("In order to disconnect, you have to connect first to an Arduino device.");
            }
        }


        //in work
        public static bool IsConnected()
        {
            return isConnected;
        }
    }
}
```

The class from my window is here:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Xander
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Arduino.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Arduino : Window
    {
        public Arduino()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        //Butonul de conectare/deconectare la SerialPort pentru conexiunea la Arduino
        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!ArduinoControl.IsConnected())
            {
                ArduinoControl.ConnectToArduino();
            }
            else
            {
                ArduinoControl.DisconnectFromArduino();
            }
        }

        //Butonul de ascundere a ferestrei ArduinoControl
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Hide();
        }

        //TODO - De verificat - NOT WORKING
        public void DisplayConnected()
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Metoda este rulata");            //WORKING
            btnConnect.Content = "Disconnect";
            lblConnectionStatus.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
            lblConnectionStatus.Content = "Connected";
        }

        //TODO - De verificat - NOT WORKING
        public void DisplayDisconnected()
        {
            btnConnect.Content = "Connect";
            lblConnectionStatus.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            lblConnectionStatus.Content = "Disconnected";
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to pass the label as a parameter into the other class

Comment: I realized what you meant by that, I tried and it did not work.

Comment: This looks like WPF code to me.  If it's anything like WinForms, your `ArduinoControl` class creates a `new Arduino();` form, but never shows it.  I'm guessing you are trying to reference the form already on the screen.

Comment: Yes, it is wpf. I guess that new Arduino() was part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the methods of the existing window instance that you see on the screen. This means that you need to get a reference to this particular instance somehow.

The easiest way to do this would be to use the `Application.Current.Windows` property:

```
public static void ConnectToArduino()
{
    try
    {

        Arduino window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Arduino>().FirstOrDefault();
        string portName = window.tboxPortName.Text;
        sp.PortName = portName;
        sp.BaudRate = 9600;
        sp.Open();
        window.DisplayConnected();
        isConnected = true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Please give a valid port number or check your connection. " +
            "If the port number is correct but the error persist, please check if your Arduino device is correctly connected.");
    }
}

public static void DisconnectFromArduino()
{
    try
    {
        sp.Close();
        isConnected = false;
        Arduino window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Arduino>().FirstOrDefault();
        window.DisplayDisconnected();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("In order to disconnect, you have to connect first to an Arduino device.");
    }
}
```